# Start python tkinter stopwatch based on arduino serial output

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino, pyserial

I have an arduino connected to a button. when the button is pressed, a serial output of 1 is sent via serial. i want the python tkinter stopwatch to start when the button is pressed. Currently i know 1 is being read by the python serial read. and prints out at python terminal. but i cant control the tkinter stopwatch. PS: i am fairly new to python. below is my current code.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM4',\
    baudrate=57600,\
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
        timeout=10)

print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)



class StopWatch(Frame):  
    """ Implements a stop watch frame widget. """                                                                
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):        
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        self._start = 0.0        
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0
        self._running = 0
        self.timestr = StringVar()               
        self.makeWidgets()      

    def makeWidgets(self):                         
        """ Make the time label. """
        l = Label(self, textvariable=self.timestr)
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        l.pack(fill=X, expand=NO, pady=2, padx=2)                      

    def _update(self): 
        """ Update the label with elapsed time. """
        self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        self._timer = self.after(50, self._update)

    def _setTime(self, elap):
        """ Set the time string to Minutes:Seconds:Hundreths """
        minutes = int(elap/60)
        seconds = int(elap - minutes*60.0)
        hseconds = int((elap - minutes*60.0 - seconds)*100)                
        self.timestr.set('%02d:%02d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds, hseconds))

    def Start(self):                                                     
        """ Start the stopwatch, ignore if running. """
        if not self._running:            
            self._start = time.time() - self._elapsedtime
            self._update()
            self._running = 1        

    def Stop(self):                                    
        """ Stop the stopwatch, ignore if stopped. """
        if self._running:
            self.after_cancel(self._timer)            
            self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start    
            self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
            self._running = 0

    def Reset(self):                                  
        """ Reset the stopwatch. """
        self._start = time.time()         
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0    
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    sw = StopWatch(root)
    sw.pack(side=TOP)


    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

    root = Tk()
    sw = StopWatch(root)
    sw.pack(side=TOP)
    count=1

    while True:
        for line in ser.read():

            print(chr(line))
            count = count+1
            if chr(line) == '1':
                sw.Start()

    ser.close()
```

Edit: As per comment answer by i have got it working. below is the working code.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import serial

class StopWatch(Frame):  
    """ Implements a stop watch frame widget. """                                                                
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):        
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        self._start = 0.0        
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0
        self._running = 0
        self.timestr = StringVar()               
        self.makeWidgets()      

    def makeWidgets(self):                         
        """ Make the time label. """
        l = Label(self, textvariable=self.timestr)
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        l.pack(fill=X, expand=NO, pady=2, padx=2)                      

    def _update(self): 
        """ Update the label with elapsed time. """
        self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        self._timer = self.after(50, self._update)

    def _setTime(self, elap):
        """ Set the time string to Minutes:Seconds:Hundreths """
        minutes = int(elap/60)
        seconds = int(elap - minutes*60.0)
        hseconds = int((elap - minutes*60.0 - seconds)*100)                
        self.timestr.set('%02d:%02d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds, hseconds))

    def Start(self):                                                     
        """ Start the stopwatch, ignore if running. """
        if not self._running:            
            self._start = time.time() - self._elapsedtime
            self._update()
            self._running = 1        

    def Stop(self):                                    
        """ Stop the stopwatch, ignore if stopped. """
        if self._running:
            self.after_cancel(self._timer)            
            self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start    
            self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
            self._running = 0

    def Reset(self):                                  
        """ Reset the stopwatch. """
        self._start = time.time()         
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0    
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)

def Read():
        ser = serial.Serial(
        port='COM4',\
        baudrate=57600,\
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
            timeout=10)

        print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)
        count=1

        while True:
                for line in ser.read():

                    print(chr(line))
                    count = count+1
                    return chr(line)

        ser.close()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    sw = StopWatch(root)
    sw.pack(side=TOP)
    ser = Read()

    if ser == '1':
        sw.Start()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: One obvious problem is that `sw.Start` doesn't call the function. It needs to be `sw.Start()`.

Comment: @BryanOakley i have updated my code because the gui wont start. now the gui starts but stop watch won't start. when i close the gui the command line interface says sw is not defined.

Comment: Well your indention is off in your `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement

Comment: @SierraMountainTech how is it off? also if i put root = Tk()
    sw = StopWatch(root)
    sw.pack(side=TOP) above the while true statement, nothing happens

Comment: `count=1` the `while True:` statement and `ser.close()` should all by in line with `main()` Also none of it will even run until your app closes unless that was your intention.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech i want the stopwatch to start while it is open. i have updated the question with your comment indentation

Comment: You are creating 2 instances of `Tk()`, `sw = StopWatch(root)` and `sw.pack(side=TOP)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154557/discussion-between-mohamed-athif-and-sierra-mountain-tech).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `main()` and `if __name__` statements are a bit broken.

You code will not run as you think it will according to what I can see in your code.

You should only be creating one instance of `Tk()` and in your code it is written twice.

Note that any code you have written after `root.mainloop()` will not run until `mainloop()` has ended. At that point your program will be closed and a new instance will have been created due to the rest of your `main()` statement.

This is probably not your intention.

This:

```
def main():
    root = Tk()
    sw = StopWatch(root)
    sw.pack(side=TOP)


    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

    root = Tk()
    sw = StopWatch(root)
    sw.pack(side=TOP)
    count=1

    while True:
        for line in ser.read():

            print(chr(line))
            count = count+1
            if chr(line) == '1':
                sw.Start()

    ser.close()
```

Should probably look like this:

```
def main():
    root = Tk()
    sw = StopWatch(root)
    sw.pack(side=TOP)

    count=1
    while True:
        for line in ser.read():
            print(chr(line))
            count = count+1
            if chr(line) == '1':
                sw.Start()

    ser.close()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is not an attempt to answer your overall problem as I have not looked at all of your code in detail yet but it would have been hard to place in a comment so I wrote it here.

UPDATE:

I am not able to test your code on anything serial related however I did modify your for loop to test the functionality of your code. With that said I believe you want to move the contents of `ser = serial.Serial()` into the `main()` function just before the `while` loop. Also maybe you should change the while loop statement just a bit. Currently the statement `while True:` will run forever.

Instead use something like this.

```
x = True
while x == True:
    # do stuff
    x = False
    sw.Start()
```

In the end I think you code should look like this:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import serial


class StopWatch(Frame):  
    """ Implements a stop watch frame widget. """                                                                
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):        
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        self._start = 0.0        
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0
        self._running = 0
        self.timestr = StringVar()               
        self.makeWidgets()      

    def makeWidgets(self):                         
        """ Make the time label. """
        l = Label(self, textvariable=self.timestr)
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        l.pack(fill=X, expand=NO, pady=2, padx=2)                      

    def _update(self): 
        """ Update the label with elapsed time. """
        self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        self._timer = self.after(50, self._update)

    def _setTime(self, elap):
        """ Set the time string to Minutes:Seconds:Hundreths """
        minutes = int(elap/60)
        seconds = int(elap - minutes*60.0)
        hseconds = int((elap - minutes*60.0 - seconds)*100)                
        self.timestr.set('%02d:%02d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds, hseconds))

    def Start(self):                                                     
        """ Start the stopwatch, ignore if running. """
        if not self._running:            
            self._start = time.time() - self._elapsedtime
            self._update()
            self._running = 1        

    def Stop(self):                                    
        """ Stop the stopwatch, ignore if stopped. """
        if self._running:
            self.after_cancel(self._timer)            
            self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start    
            self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
            self._running = 0

    def Reset(self):                                  
        """ Reset the stopwatch. """
        self._start = time.time()         
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0    
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    sw = StopWatch(root)
    sw.pack(side=TOP)
    ser = serial.Serial(
                        port='COM4',\
                        baudrate=57600,\
                        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
                        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
                        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
                            timeout=10)
    x = True
    count=1
    while x == True:
        for line in ser.read():
            print(chr(line))
            count = count+1
            if chr(line) == '1':
                sw.Start()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This prints the serial output to python commandline. but now the stopwatch gui wont even start.

Comment: if i remove the `ser = serial.Serial()` portion of your code the stopwatch window does open.

Comment: @yes it does. but now ser is not defined. and the serial output from serial does not read

Comment: @MohamedAthif correct however that tells you something is wring with either the code in `ser = serial.Serial()` or its placement.

Comment: Where can i place it? i need that bit of code to read the serial. it prints out the serial output correctly as of now

Comment: I see nothing wrong with it being in either the main() function or in the class as a method. This would at least keep it within the tkinter program and eliminate any issues being cause by it being outside of the program.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154559/discussion-between-mohamed-athif-and-sierra-mountain-tech).